# Loop through table and remove duplicate with jquery

Tags: javascript, loops, html-table, duplicates

I have a table with some date. I want to loop through the table and output the data without duplicates. How can I achieve this?

The result should be:

```
2017
2018
2019
```

```js
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
for (i=0; i < table.length; i++){
    console.log(table[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="date">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="date">2019</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to iterate through table **rows** and verify if **year** was already found.

For this, you can use a javascript **dictionary** called `var seen={}`. If the year was already found you have to set `seen[year]=true`. Otherwise, you have to hide the row by setting `display` property to `none`.

```js
var seen = {};
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (seen[td.textContent]) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        seen[td.textContent]=true;
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table">
 
 <tr>
  <td class="date">2017</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="date">2017</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="date">2018</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="date">2018</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="date">2018</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="date">2019</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="date">2019</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="date">2019</td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: @Celal, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 2):

To loop through the table and output the data without duplicates, you can use an array to hold and validate the data.

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
var data = [];
                    for (i=0; i < table.length; i++){
                if (data.indexOf(table[i].innerHTML) > -1) {
                  console.log(table[i].innerHTML);
                } else {
                  data.push(table[i].innerHTML);
                }
        }
```